# Skipping a value in map() in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a rank newcomer to javascript, thus the question,
I'm mapping through a dictionary to render a li of elements in React. This is my code,

```
<SplitButton id={this.state.title} title={this.state.title}>
          {Object.keys(dict).map(key => <MenuItem key={dict[key]} href={`#${dict[key]}`} onSelect={() => this.onTargetSelect(key,dict[key])}>{key}</MenuItem>)}
        </SplitButton>
```

I want to skip the rendering for a particular value(not key). How can I do this in Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it out first.

```js
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  skip: 3,
  d: 4
};

var result = 
    Object.keys(obj)
      .filter(key => key !== 'skip')
      .map(key => obj[key]);
console.log(result);
```